# VMware ESXi - Mixing 5.5 and 6.0 in the same datacenter

Tags: vmware-esxi

I currently have 2 clusters, both containing 5.5 hosts. Cluster A hosts the brunt of my servers, cluster B hosts a couple servers, but is primarily used as a off-site backup location for all my Veeam replicas of the VMs in cluster A.

The hosts in cluster B are getting a little long in the tooth, and I found that there raid controllers are not compatible with ESXi 6.0.

Will I run in to any issues upgrading cluster A to ESXi 6.0 while leaving cluster B on ESXi 5.5? I plan on replacing those older servers soon, but I was hoping to get this upgrade process under way.

Comment: Which specific controllers are not supported? Can you provide some hardware details?

Comment: The HP Smart Array P400 controllers have apparently lost support with 6.0.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, definitely time to get rid of the G5 systems :)

Comment: I know, I am trying, but my boss doesn't see the reason in replacing them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't run into any problems with this as long as you don't upgrade your virtual machines' hardware versions beyond what 5.5 can accept.